# Rails - Chartkick - Turning tooltip off

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I have the following barchart for which I'm trying to turn the hover tooltip off:

```
= bar_chart [["", current_admin.company.progress_to_target_this_month]], colors: [current_admin.company.progress_bar_colour]
```

From their homepage, I can make an initializer file which I've done:

config/initializers/chartkick.rb

```
Chartkick.options = {
  height: '300px',
  colors: ['#b00', '#666'],
  discrete: true,
  library: {
    pointSize: 0,
    vAxis: {
      points: false,
      legend: false,
      discrete: true
    },
    hAxis: {
      points: false,
      legend: false,
      discrete: true,
      textPosition: 'none'
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  tooltips: {
    enabled: false
  }
}
```

The options regarding vaxis and haxis all work, however I can't get anything to do with tooltips working. I've tried every variety of inserting tooltips: { enabled: false } that I can think of with no joy.

If anyone has any advise it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As of summer 2017 custom tooltips are not supported in chartkick.js. There are two open issues about this on the GitHub repository:

- [Add support for custom tooltips #86](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js/issues/86)
- [Piechart with chart.js custom tooltips #85](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js/issues/85)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any other pointer-events for the chart, then you can just set `pointer-events: none` for the `div`, which contains the chart.